# mysql birthday reminder, leap year

Tags: mysql, leap-year

I'm trying to sort out a result set that gives the 5 closest users sorted by upcoming birthday. This works perfectly until leap years comes into play. For example:

- May 15th - 96 days left
- May 15th - 97 days left

The top result is a birth at 1987 and the lower is from 1988.
u_birth is stored as yyyy-mm-dd.
Is there a simple way to sort this problem without having to rewrite the entire query?

```
SELECT u_birth, IF( DAYOFYEAR( u_birth ) >= DAYOFYEAR( NOW() ), 
          DAYOFYEAR( u_birth ) - DAYOFYEAR( NOW() ), 
          DAYOFYEAR( u_birth ) - DAYOFYEAR( NOW() ) +  
      DAYOFYEAR( CONCAT( YEAR( NOW() ), '-12-31' ) ) 
 )  
 AS distance
FROM (blog_users)
WHERE `s_agehide` = 0
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT 5
```

This query is taken and modified from the mysql manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#c7489

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's obviously a problem if your algorithm depends on the year of birth of the person. To workaround this, first find each person's next birthday after the current date, then calculate the difference between that date and now.

```
SELECT u_birth, DATEDIFF(next_birthday, NOW()) AS distance FROM (
    SELECT *, ADDDATE(birthday, INTERVAL birthday < DATE(NOW()) YEAR) AS next_birthday
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ADDDATE(u_birth, INTERVAL YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(u_birth) YEAR) AS birthday
        FROM blog_users
        WHERE s_agehide = 0
    ) AS T1
) AS T2
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Results:

```
'1992-02-29', 20
'1993-03-01', 21
'1987-05-15', 96
'1988-05-15', 96
'1988-09-18', 222
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE blog_users (u_birth NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, s_agehide INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO blog_users (u_birth, s_agehide) VALUES
('1987-05-15', 0),
('1988-05-15', 0),
('1988-09-20', 0),
('2000-01-02', 0),
('2000-01-03', 1),
('1988-09-19', 0),
('1988-09-18', 0),
('1992-02-29', 0),
('1993-03-01', 0);
```

Note that someone born on a leap day is assumed to have a birthday of 28th February on a non-leap year.

Also, your query doesn't include the user id of the user. You probably want to add this too, I'd imagine.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look, gimme a couple of minutes to try it out =)

Comment: @tired: Note that I've made a small change so that all people whose birthdays are today have distance 0, not distance 365. I changed a `NOW()` to `DATE(NOW())`.

Comment: It works as it's supposed to, however I have one followup question:
How do i retrieve additional rows from the table? I've tried in all three selects but no luck, lets say i want to retrieve s_agehide too.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @tired: I assume you mean columns, not rows? I've rewritten the query slightly to make it easier to add columns. Grab the new version, then just add any extra columns you want them to the outermost (topmost) select clause.

Comment: It works! =) Thanks alot for your complex query, you saved me hours haha, thanks again!

Comment: @tired: Thanks for the fast responses to help me improve my answer.

Comment: Wow, there are many answers for the problem, but this seems to be the only one to have passed all possible edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),
        '-',
        DATE_FORMAT((birthDate),
            '%m-%d'
        )
    ),
    fullName
FROM
    employees
WHERE
    birthDate != 0
AND(
    CONCAT(
        YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())+ 1,
        '-',
        DATE_FORMAT((birthDate),
            '%m-%d'
        )
    )BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()
    AND DATE_ADD(
        CURRENT_DATE(),
        INTERVAL 21 DAY
    )
    OR CONCAT(
        YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),
        '-',
        DATE_FORMAT((birthDate),
            '%m-%d'
        )
    )BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()
    AND DATE_ADD(
        CURRENT_DATE(),
        INTERVAL 21 DAY
    )
)
```

ps: **birthDate** is the column where i stored the date of birth of the employees.
**employees** is the table name.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `dayofyear` as anything after Feb 29th in a leap year is one day further on than usual.  Instead, extract the month and day and concat them together with today's year.  Then do the comparison.

Like so:

```
SELECT u_birth, 
  IF(DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',MONTH(u_birth),'-',DAY(u-birth))) >= DATE(NOW()),
...
```

ETA:

Just so I don't have to rewrite the expression for converting birth date to birthday, I'll stick it in a variable. I recommend you write a function that does the conversion so you can use it in a query directly.

```
SET @birthday= SELECT DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',MONTH(u_birth),'-',DAY(u-birth))) FROM users WHERE user_id=x; //obviously only good for one value, but use the example for the calculation

SELECT u_birth, 
       IF(DATE(@birthday)>=DATE(NOW()), 
          DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(@birthday, INTERVAL 1 YEAR),NOW()), 
          DATEDIFF(NOW(),@birthday)
       ) as days
FROM users WHERE user_id=x;
```

Comment: I tried replacing all dayofyear with the examples you showed, yes, the leap year issue dissappears but the value and sorting is completly off. Could you please show me the entire rewritten query?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone get inspired by this peace of code.

It worked perfectly in my case but I think there's to much date-calculation...

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-',DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_birth), '%m-%d' )), fe_users.* 
FROM `fe_users`
WHERE `date_of_birth` != 0 AND (
     CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())+1,'-',DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_birth), '%m-%d' )) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
     OR
     CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()),'-',DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(date_of_birth), '%m-%d' )) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
)
```

By this peace of SQL-Code you'll get all users of the table fe_users whose date_of_birth (saved as unix-timestamp) will be within the next 7 days. You can easily extend this to 21 days by changing the interval used by the date_add() function.